How to hook into PicoCLI to always run something for all commands before they run, but after parameter parsing and IExecutionStrategy?
How do you hook into PicoCLI to always run something, e.g. to LOG some initial greeting (or whatever), for all @Command before they run, but after the parameter parsing and an IExecutionStrategy which uses parameters?
I haven't been able to figure out where to plug this into https://github.com/enola-dev/enola/tree/main/java/dev/enola/cli.

I've been able to do this by inserting that initialization into my (existing) IExecutionStrategy. Not sure if that's the most elegant way, but that "runs at the right time", and works (for me).

Yes that is the way it is designed to be used.
